# Event Receivers for Calling Web service

Tags: event-receivers

I am having SharePoint 2010 with 1 Application Server and 1 Front End Web Server
I want to call a Web Service to send SMS (SOAP 1.2) whenever an item is added to a Custom List. I tested a Event Receiver in sandbox solution with basic change of title which worked but calling to a Web service failed in a Sandbox environment.
so I decided to do a Farm Solution .. In the Farm Solution I am not able to get the basic Update Event Receiver functional the issues I ran and struggled with
- GACDepolyment
- WebApplication

Scope (tried both WEB as well as SITE)
Used power shell commands

Currently I am stuck when I call SPEnbale command which throws an Activation Error that the Object is in Use ...

Can you please give me clear Steps on how can I write a List Item Event Receiver with the exact settings and deploying of the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is from MSDN and I see no reason why this should not work:

**To create the event handler**

1. Start Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.
2. On the **File** menu, point to **New**, and then click **Project**.
3. In **Project Types**, under **Visual Basic** or **C#**, select **Event Receiver**.
4. Type **DeletingEventReceiver** as the project name. Click **OK**.
5. In the **SharePoint Customization Wizard**, choose **Deploy as a sandboxed
   solution**. Click **Next**.
6. In the **Choose Event Receiver Settings** dialog, select **List Item
   Events** in the **What type of event receiver do you want?** dropdown.
7. In the **What item should be the event source?** dropdown, choose **Tasks**.
8. Choose the **An item is being deleted** option in the **Handle the
   following events** list. Click **Finish**.
9. In the **EventReceiver1** file that is created, insert the following
   code in the **ItemDeleting** method.

   properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
   properties.ErrorMessage = "Deleting items from " + properties.RelativeWebUrl + " is not supported.";
10. Press F5 to deploy the solution.
11. Navigate to a task list and select an item in the list. Click the
     **Delete Item** button on the Server ribbon.
12. Observe the error message.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms453149(v=office.14).aspx